# Instantiating an sqlite database with go?

Tags: go, sqlite

I have extracted the code below from my application. I am trying to create a new directory, put an sqlite database in it, then create a table in the database.

Currently it creates the directory, a file for the db to exist in and it runs without any errors. However, the db file is empty. I cannot figure out why it is empty.

Does anyone know how to modify this code so the content remains in the database?

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    os.MkdirAll("./data/1234", 0755)
    os.Create("./data/1234/data.db")

    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./data/1234/data.db")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    _, err = db.Query("CREATE TABLE `customers` (`till_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `client_id` VARCHAR(64) NULL, `first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `guid` VARCHAR(255) NULL, `dob` DATETIME NULL, `type` VARCHAR(1))")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    db.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not closing the database, so the changes aren't flushed to the database file.

Make sure you execute `db.Close()`.

You then need to use the `Exec` method, not `Query` to modify the database.

```
_, err = db.Exec("CREATE TABLE `customers` (`till_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `client_id` VARCHAR(64) NULL, `first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `guid` VARCHAR(255) NULL, `dob` DATETIME NULL, `type` VARCHAR(1))")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated my example above. The end result is the same unfortunately. data.db is created but nothing is saved to the file after the script has finished running.

Comment: @ComputerUser: missed that you're using Query too.

Comment: @JimB can you defer the close statement?

Comment: @Hooper: As long as it get's called it doesn't matter if it's in a defer or not, but that's kind of obvious, so is there a reason you're asking?

Comment: @JimB You're right. Nope - I was thinking of something else.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the function `Exec` instead of `Query` to create a table. Take a look at the documentation for those functions:

[func (*DB) Query](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query)

```
Query executes a query that returns rows, typically a SELECT. The args are for any placeholder parameters in the query.
```

[func (*DB) Exec](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Exec)

```
Exec executes a query without returning any rows. The args are for any placeholder parameters in the query.
```